# Set Android Volume In A Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, android-broadcast

I have the following code in a BroadcastReciver and for some reason won't set the volume to 0.
If I put the same code that sets the volume attached to a button on click event it works just fine. Can someone shed some light as to why this might possibly happen? I know the broadcast receiver is being invoked because I put a log message inside the if statement and it displayed.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    int volume = CommonUtilities.getSharedPreferenceInt(context, CommonUtilities.PREF_FILE, CommonUtilities.PERCENT, -1);
    boolean savedSettings = CommonUtilities.getSharedPreferenceBoolean(context, CommonUtilities.PREF_FILE, CommonUtilities.SAVED_SETTINGS, false);

    if(volume >= 0 && savedSettings){
        Log.v(CommonUtilities.TAG, "Setting the audio");
        CommonUtilities.setSharedPreferenceBoolean(context, CommonUtilities.PREF_FILE, "SetAudio", true);
        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
    }
}
```

If I put this same code in the onClick event it works just fine. The volume is set to 0 and shows the volume UI that it's set to 0.

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
```

Thank you for helping!

Comment: have you checked what volume and savedSettings are returning? sometime due to some coding mistake we get default value only. Please check

Comment: Yes, like I mentioned I put a log statement inside the if statement to make sure that code is running and sure enough the log was there.

Comment: then i don't know what the problem is since i am using this in my Service and it is working properly. May be someone else will help you good luck.

Comment: Well this is in a BroadcastReceiver does that make any difference? Would the context make a difference? I appreciate the help!

Comment: I checked it my application and it is working fine both in `Service` and in `BroadcastReciever`. I don't know why it isn't working for you. Have you tried testing it in any real device?

Comment: Do you think it could have anything to do with it's in a boot completed broadcast receiver?

Comment: the thing is it should work no matter whenever the broadcast receiver is called. I mean it's a piece of code, the application should execute it whenever it reaches it. I have been using the same lines of your code in my application numerous times and i haven't faced a single problem. That's the reason i am confused why it isn't working.

Comment: have you tried checking the value of `Stream_music` before and after your code execution? If not, try it and tell me whether your app is able to change the values or not?

Comment: I have not that's an excellent idea! I will try that thank you!

Comment: did it worked? If not then you can always put on a bounty.

Comment: Yes it did work. I knew there were several different types of themes. I thought I was setting the correct stream, but apparently not. The values before and after helped a lot thank you for the great tip.

Comment: I am glad that this worked for you. You should answer your own question and then marked this as solved.